# NativeScript Plugin Firebase token not registering to Adobe Mobile Services

Tags: firebase, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, adobe, nativescript

I'm working on a NativeScript mobile application where I'm using [`nativescript-plugin-firebase`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-plugin-firebase) to retrieve a Firebase token I then send to Adobe Mobile Services so that I can send push notifications from there to users of both platforms (Android and iOS):

```
FirebasePlugin.init({
    onMessageReceivedCallback: () => { ... },
    onPushTokenReceivedCallback: (token: string) => {
        AdobeAnalytics.getInstance().optIn();
        AdobeAnalytics.getInstance().setPushIdentifier(isAndroid ? token : new NSData({ base64Encoding: token }));
    }
});
```

This works fine on Android, where I can then send notifications from AMS to individual devices using the token or to multiple ones using AMS's segments.

However, on iOS it only works using the token, as AMS thinks there are no iOS devices registered. The requests triggered by `setPushIdentifier` returns `200 OK` and something like this on both platforms:

```
{
    "d_blob": "...",
    "d_mid": "...",
    "d_ottl": 7200,
    "dcs_region": 6,
    "ibs": [],
    "id_sync_ttl": 604800,
    "subdomain": "mysandbox",
    "tid": "..."
}
```

I use a modified version of [`nativescript-adobe-marketing-cloud`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-adobe-marketing-cloud) `1.5.0` that exposes that `setPushIdentifier`, but the implementation doesn't change.

I have also tried replacing `nativescript-plugin-firebase` with [`push-plugin`](https://github.com/NativeScript/push-plugin), in which case I get an APNs token when using iOS instead of a Firebase one:

```
PushPlugin.init({
    onMessageReceivedCallback: () => { ... },
    onPushTokenReceivedCallback: (token: string) => {
        AdobeAnalytics.getInstance().optIn();
        AdobeAnalytics.getInstance().setPushIdentifier(isAndroid ? token : new NSData({ base64Encoding: token }));
    }
});
```

But the same thing happens.

Comment: I'm not surprised Adobe can't handle the Firebase token on iOS, but I am a bit surprised the push plugin doesn't work either. Perhaps your APNs certificate isn't registered correctly with Adobe (or it's the prod one while you're testing dev?). Anyway, once https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/issues/909 is live you'll be able to use the Firebase plugin instead of the push plugin to get a regular APNs token.